# Call xll functions in c# app

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, xll

Is there any way I can import an xll into my C# WPF project? I require some of the functions that are usually called via the xll addin in Excel. I have read that xll performs like normal dlls, but sharpdevelop does not seem to be able to read any of its functions and methods. I know the formulas that are usually called in excel, can I access those same functions in my WPF app?

Comment: There is a duplicate of this exact question, it doesn't have any accepted solutions but I will add one now to give you a few options.

Comment: Dam due to this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256056/495455 I cant close this question as a dupllicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406934/calling-function-in-xll-file-from-c-sharp  **<-- see this QA for my answer**

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if  :

1. you know the prototype of the function.
2. arguments are only primitives C type , (no `xloper` type).
3. the function is independent of Excel (does not require to be initialized by excel)

then yes you can call it from C# thanks to `DllImport`