# Calling Excel C API from VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, c, excel, vsto, xll

From within an Excel VSTO (.NET) add-in, I need to call Excel C API functions (e.g. `Excel12`), in order to avoid conversion between Excel's data types (`xloper12`) and managed data.

I know how I could get access to functions defined within an XLL; so in principle, I could write an XLL more or less "forwarding" the functionality which I need. Yet I would like to avoid a "dummy" XLL.

The accepted answer to this

[Calling Excel/DLL/XLL functions from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940747/calling-excel-dll-xll-functions-from-c-sharp)

question suggests that I find the functionality I need in `xlcall32.dll`. I'm not sure this assumption is correct.

Yet how do I put that all together? Does my VSTO addin have to *load* `xlcall32.dll`?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look into the source code of the excellent Excel DNA (open source -https://exceldna.codeplex.com/ ) project by Govert to get some ideas. There is a function called "MarshalNativeToManaged" in XlCustomMarshal12.cs file wich seems to achieve your request. I'm more C++ oriented so I can't help further.

Comment: Where are you getting the xloper12s?